# How to calculate monthly price for AWS Serverless Opensearch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-opensearch

I want to know min monthly price for serverless option of Opensearch.
Docs say,

> "you will be billed for a minimum of 4 OCUs (2x indexing includes
> primary and standby, and 2x search includes one replica for HA) for
> the first collection in an account."

Min 4 OCU per hour  4 * $0.24 * 24 * 30 = 691$ per month and + s3 cost.

Is it correct or I misunderstand something?

I am asking because it looks quite pricy and we can use servers to reduce the price

Comment: Looks right to me, and IMO that required configuration is overkill if you're planning to use it for log ingestion.

Comment: Edit: There are no s3 costs unless you create snapshots in S3.

Comment: @jordanm I believe is incorret. With Serverless Opensearch, the datastore is S3, not EBS on nodes, so that implies there are s3 costs even if you don't create snapshots in S3. From the docs: "In OpenSearch Serverless, you're charged for the following components: Data ingestion compute, Search and query compute, Storage retained in Amazon S3."